# about conditionals in javascript

Tags: javascript, conditional-statements

I have some (I think they can be few stupid) questions...but they're questions, and I'd like post here, and debate it.

It's about conditionals. I'm developing in javascript, and I've some functions, and I'd like write optimal code.

For example, I have to check some conditions, so I can write:

```
if(text == ""){
//some code for finish
}else if(text== previousText){
//some code for finish
}

//here I write more code...which runs if both conditions had not complied.
```

My doubt is: **what do you think is better to do?**

**Point 1**

```
if(text == ""){
    //some code for finish
}else if(text== previousText){
    //some code for finish
}else{
    //here I write more code...which runs if both conditions had not complied.
}
```

or

**Point 2**

```
if(text == ""){
    //some code for finish using return
    return;
}else if(text== previousText){
    //some code for finish using return
    return;
}

 //here I write more code...which runs if both conditions had not complied.
```

I hope have explained well. Sometimes these things go unnoticed, but they're important, I think.
Thanks a lot, Daniel

Comment: My advice would be to not over think things like this, you will never get anything done. As long as the code works and is readable, it's fine.

Comment: This is all a matter of opinion.  Personally, I don't like multiple return statements in a function or method but some do.  I would not say one is necessarily better than the other.

Comment: Because this question doesn't really have an answer I've voting to have it closed as Not Constructive as it will just lead to debate and isn't appropriate for stackoverflow.

Comment: In my case, I have some return, so I decided post about this issue, in order to clarify me.

Comment: By using multiple return statements you are trying to avoid checking conditions once one of them is met. If else works this way. They are checked in hierarchy and if one is met it won't check after that. So with multiple returns you are trying to accomplish what is already implemented. So Point 1 would be the normal choice.

Answer (score 3):

I follow the rule to have only one `return` statement per function. So **Point 1**

Comment: that is how i was taught as well. multiple returns is discouraged